# Jquery Ajax Post Error Undefined in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am implementing a jquery ajax form submission on selecting the checkbox. I am always getting error undefined in the response data. Please find my code as following.

**Jquery Post**

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: filelink+"playlist/add_cart_item",
   data: {"product_id":id,"quantity":qty,"ajax":1},
   success: function(msg){
   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
   { 
    alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown) 
   }
  });
```

**Controller Function**

```
   function add_cart_item(){
     echo "true";
   }
```

File link is giving me the exact path. Jquery library file is also properly included. Can anybody please help where could be the problem.

**I am using HMVC Codeigniter. Is there any other way of calling php file from ajax in it ??**

Also When I am changing the type from POST to GET it is returning my ECHO "TEST" ..
Thanks

Comment: `"product_id=id&quantity=qty&ajax='1'"` should be `"product_id=" + id + "&quantity=" + qty + "&ajax=1"`

Comment: If you run this link in a browser, do you get the wanted answer?

Comment: Hi @slash197 i tried this with GET instead of POST then it do not give me error undefined but I am not getting the echo "Test" back in the msg alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several points.

1. in `add_cart_item()` try adding the [correct header for json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file)
2. Try to use `console.log` instead of `alert` for debugging javascript.
3. Try to debug the http request/response using firebug.

Comment: Kinjal thanks for replying. I used the firebug and tried to get the response. I found that it is giving 500 internal server error. I think there is something wrong with the response. I am using HMVC codeigniter..

Answer (score 0):

You had an insecure ajax call..ill recommend this way

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: filelink+"playlist/add_cart_item",
   data: {"product_id":id,"quantity":qty,"ajax":1},
   success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
   { 
   alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown) 
   }
});

function add_cart_item(){

     echo $_POST['product_id'];
    exit;

   }
```

Comment: THanks Ubercooluk...Going to try the same will be back to you.

Comment: @vikas sharma url: filelink+"playlist/add_cart_item", is this a valid location ??

Comment: yes, I mean playlist.php is a controller whose index function is working fine. but my only code in add_cart_item function is what i showed you. I am new in it, should i need to load any view ??